# Using woocommerce, need to use a specific field from the database, how?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found where in my database the information is that I need to echo out, but I don't know how to echo it out!

It's in the wp_postmeta > web_detail field - see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/isHig.png

The data I need to show on the product page is the bit where it currently says: "TJOBBE"

I need this on my content-single-product.php - for every product where this information exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use get_post_meta() function that retrieves custom fields - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/. In your case something like this:

```
$web_detail = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'web_detail' );

if ( !empty( $web_detail  ) ) {
 //do smth with this data 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed!